# Is it possible for a "false positive" medical diagnosis to be voided or expunged later?

Tags: psychiatry, diagnosis

In general, if a diagnosing clinician makes a grave error in diagnosis, is it possible to later invalidate the diagnosis on the basis of insufficiency, lack of evidence, poor judgment, or other similar reason?

For example, if someone accidentally ended up in a situation where he/she was diagnosed with a mental disorder according to the DSM, but the symptoms according to the DSM do not correspond at all to reality (For example, at least the main symptoms are missing, the study admission was less then the official time needed to diagnose someone with a specific disorder, or a similar reason), can the diagnosis be fully expunged from their medical record upon a sufficient showing of such insufficiency?

I'm not asking about getting a second opinion, refusing treatment, or getting a discharge from treatment - I'm asking about fully eradicating or expunging a diagnosis to the point where it never really "existed" *at all* in a medical or medicolegal sense. In the practice of law, a legal judgment, order, or document can often be "voided", "vacated", "quashed", "overturned" or "invalidated" by a court if it is shown to have been issued in error. Is there any similar thing in the practice of medicine?

This sort of question is, perhaps, not very interesting or relevant for the majority of patients, but it can be *very* relevant for persons who must undergo formal "fitness for duty" evaluations or must "pass" medical background checks. For example, someone aspiring to become a pilot who has a history of treatment for schizophrenia, but is currently "ok", must normally undergo a grueling, time consuming, and expensive evaluation process. If such a person could get some sort of medical evaluation stating that they never really "had" schizophrenia to begin with, that could allow them to answer "no" on the applicable medical background check forms and obtain licensure that much more easily. This question may also be relevant to victims of gaslighting - if a person was given a clinical "label" as a result of abuse inflicted upon them, removing the "stigma" of having the "label" may be a valuable form of healing even if the person doesn't have any pressing *legal* need to have the diagnosis *formally* removed.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE! I am sorry, but [for a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/502/why-was-my-self-help-question-closed-as-off-topic) we can not, and will not, give advice or potential diagnoses for any specific individual. If you have a question regarding your mental health, you should see a doctor. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can take the [tour], visit the [ask] page and [meta].

Comment: @Chris I believe this question can be salvaged if it is understood to be asking if, in general, a process exists within the practice of medicine to "invalidate", "void", "vacate", "quash", or "overturn" a prior diagnosis based on procedural issues (or other issues) in the way that a court ruling *can*.

Comment: @Robert Columbia that is exactly what is meant by this question

Comment: Thanks! Could you edit your question to say that, and omit the personal details?

Comment: probably this is better

Comment: This question is very relevant for persons who must undergo "fitness for duty" evaluations or must "pass" medical background checks. The difference between, "Yeah, I was diagnosed with that, but I haven't experienced symptoms or had any treatment since 2012 - I am probably fine now" and "The diagnosis was officially voided in 2012 by the Grand Council of Medical Diagnosis Appeals Professionals on the bases of Lack of Informed Consent, Use of a Non-Evidence-Based Practice, Failure to Take an X-Ray, Improper Billing, and Failure to Post Medical Diploma on Wall of Office" is potentially huge.

Comment: I've submitted a suggested edit to your question. Could you take a look and approve it if you feel it is appropriate, with or without changes? It is important to make the question as clear as possible but also make it clear that you are not asking for a personalized professional opinion here on this site, but just asking for general information on how things "work" in a case such as yours.

Comment: *"I'm not asking about getting a second opinion..."* in order to get a clinical diagnosis removed, you are going to have to call on a second opinion, and maybe the opinion from more than a second clinical person.